# How to check if a set is OPEN?

Tags: real-analysis

**Let $A=${$(-1)^n + \frac{2}{n} :n=1,2,3,.....$} and $B= ${$x\in Q : 0<x<1$}**

**a) What are the limit points?**

Limit points of A: ${-1,1}$

Limit points of B: $[0,1]$

**b) Is the set open? closed?**

$A$ is not closed since the limit point $-1$ is not an element of $A$.

$B$ is not closed since the limit point $0$ is not an element of $B$.

**How to check if these sets are open?**

Comment: what is the definition of an open set?

Comment: For any neighborhood around every x in ur set, the neighborhood needs to be fully contained within the set

Comment: if (a-ϵ,a+ϵ) is contained in set A?

Comment: B wont be open as the irrationals are dense. Any open set around a rational x WILL intersect an irrational and hence the neighborhood is not fully contained in the set B

Comment: You may try complement of a closed set as the definition for an open set.

Comment: A doesnt look open either as it looks less dense than the rationals!

Comment: To be clear, we're considering these as subsets of $\Bbb R$ with the usual topology?  And do you mean to refer to $\Bbb Q$, the set of rational numbers?